# Avoid for for if in Python

Tags: python, path, nested

I have a piece of code to open a serie of txt files which is like this:

```
path_name = './path/to/my/file'
file_name = 'initial_name_of_file'

kms = np.arange(0,9,1) # kilometers
ms  = np.arange(0,1000,10) # meters

for ik in kms:
    for im in ms:
        sing_fName = file_name+str(ik)+'+'+str(im)+'.txt'
        with open(path.join(path_name, sing_fName).replace("\\","/")) as profile:
            var_reader = csv.reader(profile, delimiter=',')
            if ik==8 and im==410:
                break
```

at this point I would like the code to stop when ik = 8 and im = 410, i.e. the code should go with im from 0 ro 990 while ik goes 0 to 7 and stop for im 410 if ik = 8.

My question is twofold:

1. is there a more efficient way to generate the single file names
   (sing_fName) and open the file one after the other to access the
   data?
2. How can I skip the 'for for if' nesting?

thanks!

Comment: I don't see a `if`, but have a look at `itertools`, it has a `product` function.

Comment: you're right: I edit the question.

Comment: if you really don't like 2 forloop, you may use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) or list comprehension like `for sing_fName in [ "filename%s+%s.txt"%(kms, ms) for kms in range(0, 9, 1) for ms in range(0, 1000, 10) ]:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd add an exit flag :

```
import numpy as np

path_name = './path/to/my/file'
file_name = 'initial_name_of_file'

kms = np.arange(0,9,1) # kilometers
ms  = np.arange(0,1000,10) # meters

exit = False

for ik in kms:
    if exit:
      break
    for im in ms:
        if ik==8 and im==410:
          exit = True
          break
        sing_fName = file_name+str(ik)+'+'+str(im)+'.txt'
        with open(path.join(path_name, sing_fName).replace("\\","/")) as profile:
            var_reader = csv.reader(profile, delimiter=',')
```

Comment: I've marked this as  correct because it's slightly faster, but Jean-François Fabre's solution works perfectly as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your double `for` loop.

If you want the code to stop at 410 for index 8, just define your index dynamically, so no index test in the inner loop, will definitely be faster.

For the filename, using `format` is more pythonic and probably faster too. You can also pre-compute prefix in the outer loop.

```
kms = np.arange(0,9,1) # kilometers

for ik in kms:
    prefix = "{}{}+".format(file_name,ik)
    for im in np.arange(0,420 if ik == 8 else 1000,10):  # dynamic upper bound
        sing_fName = "{}{}.txt".format(prefix,im)
        with open(path.join(path_name, sing_fName)) as profile:
```

Aside: don't convert backslashes to slashes. This has no effect except to slow down your code. Since `os.path.join` uses backslashes, it means that the system can handle it.

Comment: thanks for your answers. A couple of comments/questions:
1. I wasn't clear enough, sorry: I need all the ik from 0 to 7 to have a im from 0 to 990, ik=8 is the only one that should stop at im=410
2. concerning backslashes, if I keep them I should change path_name to  '.\\path\\to\\my\\file', right?

Comment: Edited, no `if`, just dynamic upper bound in lower for loop. And no you can use slashes for your paths, python/windows know them. Or use the raw prefix: `r"\path\to\my\file"` so no need to double the backslashes.